# Intercepting .js requests and appending .gz with node and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, angular-cli

I have an angular 2 application that I've built with the cli and gzipped.  I can serve the app from the dist folder but I would like to serve the .gz version of the js files to further increase performance.

Express server file attempts:

```
app.get('*.js', function (req, res, next) {
  req.url = req.url + '.gz';
  res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
  console.log(req,res);
  next();
});
```

also tried:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    console.log(req,res);
    var hello = req.url.split('.');
    if(hello[hello.length-1]=='js'){
        console.log(req,res);
        req.url += '.gz';
        res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
    }

    next();
});
```

Comment: I was able to use the express compression middleware, still wondering if it's possible to intercept the request.

Comment: You find an answer to your question? I am trying to accomplish the same thing. no luck.

Comment: Hey @jamesemanon I used the compression npm package and it is working well.  It reduced my site size to less than 200kb not counting images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `compression` npm module.

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/expressjs/compression#expressconnect).

Then, compression is supported by the HTTP layer, and it happens transparently. No need to modify file extensions or compress the file in advance.

The server would be doing the compression for you, unless you want to serve the compressed file directly. In this case the file compression format is inferred from the extension.

If you wish to save yourself processing time, you can put a reverse proxy cache in front of your server.

Comment: Hey that is what I did.  I added it as a comment to my original post.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? If so can you select it as the answer?